# Ubuntu - How do I pass JSON string to herestring?

Tags: ubuntu, json, here-string

## Update

I noticed that I am able to pass JSON with this command

```
command -j /dev/stdin <<< '{"key":"value"}'
```

However, it does not work if I call it through **SSH**.

```
ssh {target} 'command -j /dev/stdin <<< '{"key":"value"}''
```

Looks like it send through as a string and not JSON? Anyone have any idea why?

---

I have a command where I need to pass a JSON string to the options but for some reasons I need it to be passed using `herestring` to `/dev/stdin`.

**Example**

```
command -j /dev/stdin <<< '{"key":"value"}'
```

Comment: Your problem are the unescaped single quotes. You have ``'`` before ``command`` that is closed after ``<<<```. I think you need to use ``\'`` after ``<<<`` and after ``"value"}``. Otherwise you close the ssh single quotes at the first inner single quote and open it again at the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the here-string redirection part of the remote command.  Data redirected into `ssh` would end up on the standard input of the remote command:

```
ssh remote 'some command' <<<'whatever string'
```

In your case,

```
ssh target 'command -j /dev/stdin' <<<'{"key":"value"}'
```

But this assumes that both `key` and `value` are already JSON encoded.

Constructing the JSON with `jq` (to get proper encoding of the value, assuming it is held in a shell variable `$value`):

```
jq -nc --arg val "$value" '{ key: $val }' | ssh target 'command -j /dev/stdin'
```

Or, use `jo` to write the JSON document:

```
jo key="$value" | ssh target 'command -j /dev/stdin'
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, when passing `"` to SSH I would need to use `\\\"` to let it go through. So the command below works.

```
ssh {target} 'command -j /dev/stdin <<< '{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}''
```

Comment: Note that this would possibly not JSON encode the strings in the JSON document.